# How can I share business logic between server and client if I use RequestFactory?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Let's say I have an Employee bean which has a "dateOfBirth" property:

```java
public class Employee {
    ...
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    ... 
    public Date getDateOfBirth() {...}
    public void setDateOfBirth(Date date) {...}
    ...
}
```

In order to use RequestFactory I create EmployeeProxy:

```java
@ProxyFor (value = Employee.class)
public inteface EmployeeProxy extends EntityProxy {
    ... 
    Date getDateOfBirth();
    void setDateOfBirth(Date date);
    ...
}
```

Now let's say I have a static method which given an Employee it returns his age:

```java
public class Util {
    public static int getAge(Employee e) {
        return (new Date()).getYear()-e.getDateOfBirth().getYear();
    }
}
```

If I were not using RequestFactory and have the Employee class in the client as well, I could share "Util" between server and client and invoke getAge() for Employee instances on the client.
Since I'm using RequestFactory I suppose I have to create a new version of Util for the client like this:

```java
public class Util {
    public static int getAge(EmployeeProxy e) {
        return (new Date()).getYear()-e.getDateOfBirth().getYear();
    }
}
```

What could be a good solution to make an Util version for both the client and the server?

This is trivial but I actually have some complex calculation which I often could do on the client and spare a round-trip. The main reason I like RequestFactory is because it transfers only modified values on updates.
My domain classes are simple POJOs which I could share with client with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice - Your Employee class should be implementing EmployeeProxy interface.

Would that not solve your problem of using Util class on server side too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a simple solution, but I would have to work on my server with proxy classes, it doesn't seem much clean. Also, my domain classes are auto generated and I would have to add the implement statement each time after the generation. I'm considering not using RequestFactory at all.